# Spreadsheet::WriteExcel : Dynamic usage to create charts in a same worksheet

Tags: excel, perl, loops, charts

I actually work on an automation to draw automatically some curves in the same workseet.

I would like to know if someone has tips for me to create a dynamic code to draw chart with the library Spreadsheet::WriteExcel.

I would like to use a for loop to create several charts in the same worksheet. I tried several methods but I do not know how to declare the chart to add with my loop without overwriting it each time.

My code is the following :

sub ExcelGraphGen {

```
my ($RowMin,$RowMax,$ColMin,$ColMaxToRead,$NumOfColumnMeasured,$wbToWrite,$TableOfWsToDraw_REF,$TableOfWsToWrite_REF,$Voltage_REF,$Columns) = @_;

#For all VG Values
my @Alphabet = ("A".."ZZ");

foreach my $Voltage [3,2,1,0] {              

    for (my $i=0 ; $i< 3 ; $i++) {

        my $chart = $wbToWrite->add_chart( type => 'scatter', embedded => 1, name => "$i" );
        my $WorkSheetNameToParse = $TableOfWsToWrite{$Voltage}->get_name();
        my $WorkSheetNameToDraw = $TableOfWsToDraw{$Voltage}->get_name();

        for (my $ColToRead = $i ; $ColToRead < 9; $ColToRead = $ColToRead + 3  ) {

            $chart->add_series(
                name => "\'${WorkSheetNameToParse}\'\!\$${Alphabet[$ColToRead]}\$3",
                categories => "=${WorkSheetNameToParse}\!\$A\$5:\$A${RowMax}",
                values => "=${WorkSheetNameToParse}\!${Alphabet[$ColToRead]}\$5:${Alphabet[$ColToRead]}${RowMax}",
            );
        }
    $TableOfWsToDraw{$Voltage}->insert_chart( 'E2', $chart );

    }
}
return 1;
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$TableOfWsToDraw{$Voltage}->insert_chart( 'E2', $chart );` always inserts chart into the same cell E2 and overwrites it. You need to use different cells based on $i. For example: `'E'.(2 + $i)`.
You may need to adjust the width and height of cells to avoid charts overlapping.